# How to make a point plot with factors in the X axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to get the a plot for demonstrative purpose (I know it my not make statistical sense, but it's precisely to discuss that). The plot must have factors in the X axis (Data$Site) and a certain value in the Y axis(Data$Count). For each "Site" a point must be appear with a size equal to the Data$Mean. My current code and it's results are as follows:

```
> is.factor(Data$Site)
TRUE
> Data$Site
[1] Creek  Shade  Valley
Levels: Creek Shade Valley

> Data$Count
[1] 2.1 3.0 8.5

> Data$Mean
[1] 1.456 2.3445 1.345

plot(Data$Site, Data$Count, type = "p", pch=15, cex=Data$Mean)
```

[image]

Obviously, I don't want lines. I want points that are of the size of Data$Mean. Is there quick and neat a way to do it in R? I have reviewed other packages like lattice and ggplot to not avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the default method - plot.default() while turning the axes off. Then use the axis() function to create custom axes. I used a 1/20 scale for my means before using them to set cex. You may not need to do this for your data.

```
d<-data.frame(Site=c('A','B','C'),
              Mean=c(15,25,60),
              Count=c(100,200,400))
> is.factor(d$Site)
[1] TRUE

plot.default(d$Site,d$Count,type='p',axes = FALSE,cex=d$Mean/20)
axis(side = 1, at = as.numeric(d$Site), labels = d$Site)
axis(side=2, at=d$Count, labels = d$count)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I just applied your suggestion and it worked great! But I have a doubt, is there a way to plot this by decresing number?

Comment: Just found out: `plot.default(d$Count, type = 'p', axes = F)` then axis are added like in your example.

Comment: If you only set the side argument for `axis` (e.g. `axis(2)`) and skip the rest, it'll draw "pretty" ticks instead of relying on data points.

Comment: Whilst `axes=FALSE` removes all four axes, ticks and lables, You can use `xaxt='n'` to only remove the x-Axis ticks and lables and add them later with `axis(side=2, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `symbols` instead of `plot`, also from the basic `graphics` package:

```
Data <- data.frame(Site = c("Creek", "Shade", "Valley"), Count = c(2.1, 3.0, 8.5), Mean = c(1.456, 2.3445, 1.345))
symbols(Data$Site, Data$Count, circles = Data$Mean, inches = 0.5)
```

You can change the symbols into other types such as `squares` and `stars`. Argument `inches` is set to reduce the overal sizes from the default value of (`1` or `TRUE`). as Please refer to `?symbols` for more information

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)

Data <- data.frame(
  Site=c("Creek", "Shade", "Valley"),
  Count=c(2.1, 3.0, 8.5),
  Mean=c(1.456, 2.3445, 1.345)
)

ggplot(Data, aes(x=Site, y=Count, size=Mean)) + geom_point()
```

[image]